# Filemaker Webdirect popup?

Tags: scripting, popup, filemaker

Since printing is not compatible with Filemaker WebDirect as desired, I alternatively want to do a popup window of the printable layout similar to the way I see it done with Google Maps, so in my scripting logic if Get(SystemPlatform) = 4, I want to have a popup layout with no buttons to go back and such and assuming the user will need to not block such popups anyways.

Is there a way to get a popup to work for this? I tried display as popover and that didn't seem to work as desired since it also printed the backgroud as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Google Maps handles this. I tried loading a map and choosing the "Print" option from their menu. Doing so removed the search box and instead gave me a header where I could add notes and print or cancel. That much could be accomplished by just navigating to a different layout.

If I'm understanding this incorrectly and you want a JavaScript popup similar to what I see when I click the "Image" button while filling in this answer, that's not something you can probably do with WebDirect. I think you'll have to do one of two things:

- Build a Custom Web Publishing page using the PHP API and integrate that using an `Open URL` script step
- Use a Web Viewer within the WebDirect layout, allowing the Web Viewer to take over the entire layout space

Comment: Looks like what I alternatively do is when I'm in an application page in WebDirect, I could have a button to go to printable layout view so the user can print from the browser menu.  My concern is whether on not having a "Go back" button in WebDirect (hiddenable in Pro) would appear in printer output or not.

Comment: If you're wondering if the "Go back" button will appear on the printout, might I suggest you try it first and see if it's actually a problem?